# What does "clock" mean?

Tags: meaning

Anna critizes her lover Vronsky about her husband Alexie:

> Anna: Why do you call him my husband? He isn't my husband, he's a
> **clock**.

What does "clock" mean?

Comment: A clock is a machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clock means what it usually means, a timekeeping machine.  More context would be needed to know exactly why she is saying this though.  Without more context, she is literally saying that Alexie is a clock, an inanimate object, not a human being.  There could be a number of different reasons to say this, each with its own context.

- She might be saying he is worth more as a clock than a person, because he is very punctual and obsessed with being on time.
- She might be saying that he is worthless as a human being, and she considers him to be equivalent to an inanimate object, and could have replaced "clock" in this sentence with any object, such as "coat rack" or "deck chair".
- She might be saying that she has no husband, and that she is simply pretending he doesn't exist... she is "seeing through" him as if he were invisible, and all she can see is the clock that is on the other side of him.
- She might be saying something else that would be evident from context.

Without the context, we can't answer this for certain.

Comment: She could be saying he is a 'clock' because, like a clock, he has a face and is capable of action of a predictable, dull, limited, mechanical kind.

Comment: Yep, that's another one that would be clear from context.

Comment: From what I remember, Alexei  Karenin is a very cold, unemotional person. I think Anna is saying that he is more like a machine than a man.

Comment: I would discard your 3rd point, she wouldn't use the masculine pronoun "he" if she was pretending Alexei was invisible, she'd go with it, referring to the actual clock behind him.